# How to detect data types in Crystal if they cannot be determined at compile-time?

Tags: types, conditional-statements, ethereum, compile-time, crystal-lang

I'm writing a recursive encoder in [crystal-lang](/questions/tagged/crystal-lang) for the [Ethereum RLP](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/rlp) standard.

What I have to do is taking any incoming data blob that is to be encoded and determine it's type. For now, I can ignore invalid types for the sake of simplicity.

Valid types for RLP encoding would be binary `Bytes`, strings `String`, or lists of strings `Array(String)`. So far, so good, I wrote three methods that allow for the three data types:

```
module Rlp
  # rlp-encodes binary data
  def self.encode(b : Bytes)
    return "binary #{typeof(b)} #{b}"
  end

  # rlp-encodes lists data
  def self.encode(l : Array(String))
    return "listsy #{typeof(l)} #{l}"
  end

  # rlp-encodes string data
  def self.encode(s : String)
    return "strngy #{typeof(s)} #{s}"
  end
end
```

Now, however, there is some depth here because arrays can be nested. Therefore, this encoder is recursive. Given an `Array(String)` it gives it some prefix and encodes the `String` with `Rlp.encode(s : String)`. Now, the logic for having a nested array would be to call `.encode` as often as required to encode everything. However, I fail to wrap my head around how to determine the type at compile-time.

For example:

```
 79 | Rlp.encode([["a", "b", "c"], ["cow", "dog", "cat"]])
          ^-----
Error: no overload matches 'Rlp.encode' with type Array(Array(String))
```

Right, because I don't have any `self.encode(l : Array(Array(String)))` implemented and I cannot know the nesting depth here to potentially implement all possible cases.

I tried to implement less strict wrapper method `self.encode(data)` that does not specify a data type, however, I can basically do nothing with `data` because the compiler implies data types based on my usage, i.e.:

```
# rlp-encodes _any_ data
def self.encode(data)
  if typeof(data) == Int32
    return Bytes.new data
  elsif typeof(data) == Char
    return String.new data
  end
end
```

Passing `32` of type `Int32` would cause:

```
 45 | return String.new data
Error: no overload matches 'String.new' with type Int32
```

Even though this code wouldn't be called with data of type `Int32`. I'm not sure how to proceed here. Is there anyway to be smarter about the types used while being agnostic at compile-time?

Ideally, I would just accept *any* data as input and handle the different cases myself.

Comment: Using typeof won't restrict the type of the variable inside the if. Use `if data.is_a?(Array)`, etc. But Brian's suggestion is good/better too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you declare the `Rlp.encode` for Array as follow, the compiler will take care of instantiating that method for the different types of arrays.

```
module Rlp
  # rlp-encodes lists data
  def self.encode(l : Array)
    return "listsy #{typeof(l)} #{l}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a bit heavy-handed here by converted all values `.to_s`

```
# rlp-encodes lists data
def self.encode(l : Array)
  encode(l.flatten.compact.map(&.to_s))
end

def self.encode(l : Array(String))
  return "listsy #{typeof(l)} #{l}"
end
```